# Solve partial differential equation with complex values using Deepxde

Tags: python

I would like to solve a partial differential equation (PDE) with complex values as follow:
[PDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYr0s.png)

I tried to write the code as follow:

```
import deepxde as dde
from deepxde.backend import pytorch
import numpy as np

geom = dde.geometry.Interval(0, 10000)

f = 0.1
omega = 2 * np.pi * f
mu = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7
sigma = 100
xc = 100
a = np.sqrt(-1j * omega * mu * sigma)


def pde(x, y):
    y_real, y_imag = y[:, 0:1], y[:, 1:2]
    dy_xx_real = dde.grad.hessian(y_real, x, component=None, i=0, j=0)
    dy_xx_imag = dde.grad.hessian(y_imag, x, component=None, i=0, j=0)

    # dy_xx = dde.grad.hessian(y, x)
    # return dy_xx + omega * mu * sigma * y
    return [dy_xx_real - omega * mu * sigma * y_imag, dy_xx_imag + omega * mu * sigma * y_real]


def boundary_dirichlet(x, on_boundary):
    return on_boundary and dde.utils.isclose(x[0], 0)


def boundary_robin(x, on_boundary):
    return on_boundary and dde.utils.isclose(x[0], xc)


def func1(x):
    return 1


bc_1 = dde.icbc.DirichletBC(geom, func1, boundary_dirichlet)
bc_3_real = dde.icbc.RobinBC(geom, lambda x, y: -np.real(a)*y, boundary_robin)
bc_3_imag = dde.icbc.RobinBC(geom, lambda x, y: -np.imag(a)*y, boundary_robin)


data = dde.data.PDE(geom, pde, [bc_1, bc_3_real, bc_3_imag], 16, 5, solution=None, num_test=100)


layer_size = [1] + [50] * 3 + [1]
activation = "tanh"
initializer = "Glorot uniform"
net = dde.nn.FNN(layer_size, activation, initializer)


model = dde.Model(data, net)
model.compile("adam", lr=0.001, metrics=["l2 relative error"])
losshistory, train_state = model.train(iterations=5000)

dde.saveplot(losshistory, train_state, issave=True, isplot=True)
```

and I got the error message:

C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\python.exe C:/Users/Thinkpad/anaconda3/envs/PINNs/Lib/site-packages/deepxde/data/gsghjsg.py
Using backend: pytorch
Other supported backends: tensorflow.compat.v1, tensorflow, jax, paddle.
paddle supports more examples now and is recommended.
Compiling model...
'compile' took 0.579541 s

Training model...

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\data\gsghjsg.py", line 53, in 
losshistory, train_state = model.train(iterations=5000)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\utils\internal.py", line 22, in wrapper
result = f(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\model.py", line 631, in train
self._test()
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\model.py", line 820, in _test
) = self._outputs_losses(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\model.py", line 541, in *outputs_losses
outs = outputs_losses(inputs, targets, auxiliary_vars)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\model.py", line 316, in outputs_losses_train
return outputs_losses(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\model.py", line 304, in outputs_losses
losses = losses_fn(targets, outputs*, loss_fn, inputs, self)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\data\data.py", line 13, in losses_train
return self.losses(targets, outputs, loss_fn, inputs, model, aux=aux)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\data\pde.py", line 140, in losses
f = self.pde(inputs, outputs_pde)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\data\gsghjsg.py", line 18, in pde
dy_xx_imag = dde.grad.hessian(y_imag, x, component=None, i=0, j=0)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 283, in hessian
return hessian._Hessians(ys, xs, component=component, i=i, j=j, grad_y=grad_y)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 250, in **call**
self.Hs[key] = Hessian(y, xs, component=component, grad_y=grad_y)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 223, in **init**
grad_y = jacobian(y, xs, i=component, j=None)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 181, in jacobian
return jacobian._Jacobians(ys, xs, i=i, j=j)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 153, in **call**
return self.Js[key](i, j)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 39, in **call**
raise ValueError("i={} is not valid.".format(i))
ValueError: i=0 is not valid.

Process finished with exit code 1

Could you please help me to solve the problem, thank you so much.

Best wishes,
Tony

I have attempted to debug the code but failed. I hope to get some help.

Comment: You are not allowed to put `i=0` in line 18: `pde dy_xx_imag = dde.grad.hessian(y_imag, x, component=None, i=0, j=0)`

Comment: @Marius
Dear Marius,
Thank you for your comment. Do you mean code in line 18 should be dy_xx_imag = dde.grad.hessian(y_imag, x, component=None, j=0) ?

and the other code keep unchanged ?

But I also get these messages:

  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\envs\PINNs\Lib\site-packages\deepxde\gradients.py", line 39, in __call__
    raise ValueError("i={} is not valid.".format(i))
ValueError: i=0 is not valid.

Process finished with exit code 1